# Windows: Auto start PM2 and node apps

Tags: node.js, windows, restart, pm2

At a Windows AWS server i have a NODE app and
i'm using PM2 to launch the app

I have tried the NPMs: "pm2-windows-startup" and "pm2-windows-service"

But after i restart my AWS instance and run

```
PM2 ls
```

No node app shows up in the list...

**I followed the instructions ...**

1. Installed the NPM (So PM2 auto start after reboot)
2. PM2 start myApp.js --name mySuperApp
3. PM2 save
4. Reboot
5. PM2 ls --> no running node apps? :-(

**The PM2 logs dont contain any thing...**

I have not added any ENV variables explicit (when i tried PM2 could not start any more - so i created a fresh AWS windows instance and installed every thing from scratch again...)

PM2 is located the default place (i have not changed any paths)

```
C:\Users\Administrator\.pm2
```

**My PM2 file contains:**

2017-03-13 07:37:48: ===============================================================================
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
--- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------

2017-03-13 07:37:48: Time                 : Mon Mar 13 2017 07:37:48 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
PM2 version          : 2.4.2
2017-03-13 07:37:48: Node.js version      : 6.10.0
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
Current arch         : x64
2017-03-13 07:37:48: PM2 home             : C:\Users\Administrator.pm2
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
PM2 PID file         : C:\Users\Administrator.pm2\pm2.pid
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
RPC socket file      : \.\pipe\rpc.sock
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
BUS socket file      : \.\pipe\pub.sock
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
Application log path : C:\Users\Administrator.pm2\logs
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
Process dump file    : C:\Users\Administrator.pm2\dump.pm2
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
Concurrent actions   : 2
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
2017-03-13 07:37:48: ===============================================================================

2017-03-13 07:37:48: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:mySuperApp id:0
2017-03-13 07:37:48: 
App name:mySuperApp id:0 online
2017-03-13 07:40:45: ===============================================================================

2017-03-13 07:40:45: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
2017-03-13 07:40:45: 
Time                 : Mon Mar 13 2017 07:40:45 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2017-03-13 07:40:45: 
PM2 version          : 2.4.2
2017-03-13 07:40:45: Node.js version      : 6.10.0
2017-03-13 07:40:45: 
Current arch         : x64
2017-03-13 07:40:45: PM2 home             : C:\Users\Administrator.pm2
2017-03-13 07:40:45: 
PM2 PID file         : C:\Users\Administrator.pm2\pm2.pid
2017-03-13 07:40:45: RPC socket file      : \.\pipe\rpc.sock
2017-03-13 07:40:45:
BUS socket file      : \.\pipe\pub.sock
2017-03-13 07:40:45: Application log path : C:\Users\Administrator.pm2\logs
2017-03-13 07:40:45: 
Process dump file    : C:\Users\Administrator.pm2\dump.pm2
2017-03-13 07:40:45: Concurrent actions   : 2
2017-03-13 07:40:45: 
SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
2017-03-13 07:40:45: ===============================================================================

**My PM2 DUMB file contains:**

[
  {
    "exec_mode": "fork_mode",
    "watch": false,
    "treekill": true,
    "autorestart": true,
    "automation": true,
    "pmx": true,
    "vizion": true,
    "name": "mySuperApp",
    "node_args": [],
    "pm_exec_path": "c:\mypath\mySuperApp\server.js",
    "env": {
      "windir": "C:\Windows",
      "USERPROFILE": "C:\Users\Administrator",
      "USERNAME": "Administrator",
      "USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE": "EC2AMAZ-REBQJDK",
      "USERDOMAIN": "EC2AMAZ-REBQJDK",
      "TMP": "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2",
      "TEMP": "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2",
      "SystemRoot": "C:\Windows",
      "SystemDrive": "C:",
      "SESSIONNAME": "RDP-Tcp#1",
      "PUBLIC": "C:\Users\Public",
      "PSModulePath": "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\",
      "PROMPT": "$P$G",
      "ProgramW6432": "C:\Program Files",
      "ProgramFiles(x86)": "C:\Program Files (x86)",
      "ProgramFiles": "C:\Program Files",
      "ProgramData": "C:\ProgramData",
      "PROCESSOR_REVISION": "3f02",
      "PROCESSOR_LEVEL": "6",
      "PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER": "Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel",
      "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE": "AMD64",
      "PM2_USAGE": "CLI",
      "PM2_INTERACTOR_PROCESSING": "true",
      "PATHEXT": ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC",
      "Path": "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm",
      "OS": "Windows_NT",
      "NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS": "1",
      "LOGONSERVER": "\\EC2AMAZ-REBQJDK",
      "LOCALAPPDATA": "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local",
      "HOMEPATH": "\Users\Administrator",
      "HOMEDRIVE": "C:",
      "ComSpec": "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe",
      "COMPUTERNAME": "EC2AMAZ-REBQJDK",
      "CommonProgramW6432": "C:\Program Files\Common Files",
      "CommonProgramFiles(x86)": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files",
      "CommonProgramFiles": "C:\Program Files\Common Files",
      "CLIENTNAME": "THESILVERFOX",
      "APPDATA": "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming",
      "ALLUSERSPROFILE": "C:\ProgramData",
      "PM2_HOME": "C:\Users\Administrator\.pm2",
      "mySuperApp": {}
    },
    "pm_cwd": "c:\mypath\mySuperApp",
    "exec_interpreter": "node",
    "pm_out_log_path": "C:\Users\Administrator\.pm2\logs\mySuperApp-out-0.log",
    "pm_err_log_path": "C:\Users\Administrator\.pm2\logs\mySuperApp-error-0.log",
    "pm_pid_path": "C:\Users\Administrator\.pm2\pids\mySuperApp-0.pid",
    "km_link": false,
    "NODE_APP_INSTANCE": 0,
    "vizion_running": false,
    "windir": "C:\Windows",
    "USERPROFILE": "C:\Users\Administrator",
    "USERNAME": "Administrator",
    "USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE": "EC2AMAZ-REBQJDK",
    "USERDOMAIN": "EC2AMAZ-REBQJDK",
    "TMP": "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2",
    "TEMP": "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2",
    "SystemRoot": "C:\Windows",
    "SystemDrive": "C:",
    "SESSIONNAME": "RDP-Tcp#1",
    "PUBLIC": "C:\Users\Public",
    "PSModulePath": "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\",
    "PROMPT": "$P$G",
    "ProgramW6432": "C:\Program Files",
    "ProgramFiles(x86)": "C:\Program Files (x86)",
    "ProgramFiles": "C:\Program Files",
    "ProgramData": "C:\ProgramData",
    "PROCESSOR_REVISION": "3f02",
    "PROCESSOR_LEVEL": "6",
    "PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER": "Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel",
    "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE": "AMD64",
    "PM2_USAGE": "CLI",
    "PM2_INTERACTOR_PROCESSING": "true",
    "PATHEXT": ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC",
    "Path": "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm",
    "OS": "Windows_NT",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS": "1",
    "LOGONSERVER": "\\EC2AMAZ-REBQJDK",
    "LOCALAPPDATA": "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local",
    "HOMEPATH": "\Users\Administrator",
    "HOMEDRIVE": "C:",
    "ComSpec": "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe",
    "COMPUTERNAME": "EC2AMAZ-REBQJDK",
    "CommonProgramW6432": "C:\Program Files\Common Files",
    "CommonProgramFiles(x86)": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files",
    "CommonProgramFiles": "C:\Program Files\Common Files",
    "CLIENTNAME": "THESILVERFOX",
    "APPDATA": "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming",
    "ALLUSERSPROFILE": "C:\ProgramData",
    "PM2_HOME": "C:\Users\Administrator\.pm2",
    "status": "online",
    "pm_uptime": 1489390668484,
    "axm_actions": [],
    "axm_monitor": {
      "Loop delay": {
        "alert": {},
        "agg_type": "avg",
        "value": "36.91ms"
      }
    },
    "axm_options": {
      "default_actions": true,
      "transactions": false,
      "http": false,
      "http_latency": 200,
      "http_code": 500,
      "ignore_routes": [],
      "profiling": true,
      "errors": true,
      "alert_enabled": true,
      "custom_probes": true,
      "network": false,
      "ports": false,
      "ignoreFilter": {
        "method": [
          "OPTIONS"
        ],
        "url": []
      },
      "excludedHooks": [],
      "module_conf": {},
      "module_name": "mySuperApp",
      "module_version": "2.4.2",
      "pmx_version": "1.0.3",
      "error": true
    },
    "axm_dynamic": {},
    "created_at": 1489390668484,
    "restart_time": 0,
    "unstable_restarts": 0,
    "versioning": null,
    "node_version": "6.10.0"
  }
]

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**UPDATE 16 FEB 2020:**

If it is important to you that PM2 automatically starts up without you logging into the machine (after reboot) please follow my new set of instructions instead of the old ones.

**New instructions (recommended):**

**Prerequisites (part # 1):**

First, I have installed `NPM` in a location which is available to all users. Depending on your use-case(s) it might not be necessary. But if you like to change your default location of `NPM` - you should do it first (before continuing). Here is how you change it to the location (in terminal as administrator): `C:\NodeJS\npm`:

```
npm config set prefix "C:\\NodeJS\\npm"
npm config set cache "C:\\NodeJS\\npm-cache"
npm config set temp "C:\\NodeJS\\temp"
npm config ls -l (this will list all NPM settings -> look for the 3 lines/changes marked as `overriden`)
```

**Prerequisites (part # 2):**

1. Add and set `PM2_HOME` in `System environments` (not user environments). Like: `PM2_HOME` = `C:\NodeJS\npm`
2. Add `C:\NodeJS\npm` to the existing system PATH variable (Then you are sure it will work - there has been some issues reported that `PM2_HOME` not always working).
3. Close all terminals and open them again (as administrator). Your terminal windows will now be aware of your environment changes.

**Prerequisites (part # 3):**

1. npm install pm2 -g
2. npm i pm2-windows-service -g
3. npm install -g npm-check-updates

Currently there is a bug in a module which the package `pm2-windows-service` uses - so lets fix this as well, please follow the steps below:

1. In terminal `cd` into: `C:\NodeJS\npm\node_modules\pm2-windows-service`
2. `ncu inquirer` this only outputs the existing and the newest available version of the `inquirer` module we need to update, currently: version: `1.1.2` --> `7.0.4`.
3. `ncu inquirer -u` this will update your packages.json file.
4. `npm install` this will download and update the `inquirer` module (please be aware if you don't use specific version syntax in your `packages.json` file or you have made manually changes --> other modules would be updated as well.

**Install and setup PM2 (as a service) to automatically startup after reboot:**

5. In terminal `cd` into: `C:\NodeJS\npm\node_modules\pm2-windows-service`
6. `pm2-service-install -n PM2_STARTUP_SCRIPT` (`PM2_STARTUP_SCRIPT` will be the "Display name" of the Windows service. Change it to what you prefer and hit `ENTER`.)
7. Perform environment setup (recommended)? `Yes`
8. Set PM2_HOME? `No` (No need - You have set it already)
9. Set PM2_SERVICE_SCRIPTS (the list of start-up scripts for pm2)? `Yes`
10. Set the list of startup scripts/files (semi-colon separated json config
    files or js files) `ENTER` (when nothing is entered - it will default to use PM2's `dump.pm2` file - which is created when you run `PM2 -f save`, I will return and explain this later on).
11. Set PM2_SERVICE_PM2_DIR (the location of the global pm2 to use with the service)? `Yes`
12. Specify the directory containing the pm2 version to be used by the
    service? `ENTER`

**PM2 service installed and started.**

13. Open Services in Windows and change the service to run as Administrator (or your preferred role).

**Setup the app(s) you like PM2 to startup - when shutdown or after a reboot:**

1. `pm2 start myApp.js --name mySuperApp`
2. `pm2 -f save`
3. reboot or if you use AWS (or any other cloud provider). Reboot your instance - wait 5 minutes and then log into the machine and execute `pm2 ls` and check your app has been up and running for ~ 5 min (and not only few secs because you just logged in).

**Uninstall and cleanup "pm2-windows-startup" from your registry (if you switch from my "old instruction" to the new ones):**

1. npm uninstall pm2-windows-startup -g
2. Delete the `PM2` key from registry like in the picture below:

[image]

**Old instructions (not recommended):**

**My old answer below is still working - but PM2 doesn't startup unless you log into the machine because it is loading PM2 from registry and doesn't run it as a service.**

I don't know why - but after several attempts this worked out (at a fresh installed AWS Windows 2016 BASE instance)

1. npm install pm2 -g
2. npm install pm2-windows-startup -g
3. pm2-startup install
4. pm2 start myApp.js --name mySuperApp
5. pm2 save
6. reboot
7. pm2 ls

Comment: Thanks for this mate. Using it in our office.

Comment: yeah my friend using windows and it helps me alot :)

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: It works for me only in case if I logged in into my windows server. If I didn't login into my server, pm2 is not starting up.

Comment: This seems a feasible solution, I did try in my windows server, it saved dump.pm2 for running process. However, when I restarted my server and ran pm2 ls, no process was running. P.S. I ran pm2 resurrect and it started the process again. I do not want to run that manually. What I am missing? Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what's the service name on Windows service list? Btw, your answer works like a charm in Windows 10.

Comment: Bulla: Did you fix it?
Hagen: pm2-windows-startup -> Utility to make PM2 automatically resurrect on Windows startup. The utility achieves this by adding the right registry entry (not via a service).

Comment: NB: "PM2 ls" will only list the processes which were started and saved by the same user. I realized that - when playing with PM2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @PabloDK I installed npm in d:\nodejs. I can't create a directory npm since a file named npm already exists. Am I supposed to install nodejs elsewhere?

Comment: @GinaMarano It sounds like you have already NodeJS and npm installed (npm is default installed along with NodeJS - inside the NodeJS folder). Try to run: "node --version" + "npm --version" in your terminal. If both return their version number - you are all good :) If you somehow messed up the installation files simply uninstall NodeJS completely, restart and re-install. Cheers!

Comment: @PabloDK I am confused. Is PM2_HOME = C:\NodeJS\npm pointing at a directory or a file? in my c:\nodejs directory, npm with no extension, is a file. c:\nodejs contains 1 directory (node_modules) and 8 files.There is no npm directory, npm-cache. I am installing node-v12.16.2-x64.msi.

Comment: @PabloDK I moved on making a directory c:\nodejs\npmdir and am using that. using "npm config ls -l" I noticed that there are more settings pointing to my user directory (tmp = "C:\\Users\\GMARANO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2", userconfig = "C:\\Users\\gmarano\\.npmrc",...) Are those ok?

Comment: @PabloDK using c:\nodejs\npmdir instead of c:\nodejs\npm and following the rest of the instructions worked great!

Comment: @GinaMarano I'm happy to hear that! :-)

Comment: Is `c:\nodejs\npm` referencing the actual file `npm` which does not come with a file extension, or is that a folder path?  Is that file the *actual* npm executable/binary, when you run npm at a command line?

Comment: @NamedArray No - the "NPM" file contains a script which ref. this file: node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js you can try and open up the NPM file in a text-editor and check it yourself for a better understanding :)

Comment: Stuck after responding to `Perform environment setup (recommended)? Yes`

Comment: I had to add `C:\NodeJS\npm` to the system Path varaible or it wouldn't recognize some commands

Comment: I had to `npm install inquirer@7.0.4 --save`, because the newest version is incompatible (9. something)

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE 08/06/2022**

I found out that `npm i -g pm2` is global install **per user**.
it means that if another user logged in into the server, he won't have pm2 install - because `-g` is not fully global as we want it to be.

so the solution for those who wants it fully globall:

## Configure pm2

1. create folder `c:\etc`
2. install pm2 in this folder `cd c:\etc` `npm i pm2`
3. add `C:\etc\node_modules\.bin` to the System variable `PATH`
4. type `pm2` to initialize and create the `.pm2` folder
5. copy it from `C:\Users\USER\.pm2` to `C:\etc\.pm2`
6. set a new System Variable (not user level) name: `PM2_HOME` value: `c:\etc\.pm2`

## Configure pm2

<s>1. `npm i -g pm2`
2. type `pm2` to initialize and create the `.pm2` folder
3. copy it from `C:\Users\USER\.pm2` to `C:\etc\.pm2`
3. set a new System Variable (not user level) name: `PM2_HOME` value: `c:\etc\.pm2`</s>

## Runnning your app with pm2

7. run your pm2 app. ie: `pm2 start app.js --name=MY_API` .
8. `pm2 save` to create a dump of the current apps running.

## Testing app

9. to test everything is working, try: `pm2 kill` and then `pm2 resurrect` (app should be running, check with `pm2 status` )

## Run at startup

now we need to perform the resurrect command at startup, so:

10. `npm install -g @innomizetech/pm2-windows-service`
11. `pm2-service-install -n PM2 --unattended`

thats it.

Comment: after "pm2-service-install -n PM2 --unattended" I don't see the PM2 service inside Services list. Does anyone else has this issue?

Answer (score 15):

I tried all of the above with no luck.
What worked for me:

1. create a bat file the `pm2 resurrect` command
2. create a shortcut of that file
3. pasting that shortcut on the startup folder (win+R , shell:startup)

Comment: It does pop up a CMD window for a moment on log-in, but for those not needing PM2 to run before log-in this method has way fewer downsides than the `pm2-windows-service`.

Comment: By far the best answer

Answer (score 9):

`pm2-windows-startup` works great if you're okay with the fact that it is launched on login. If you have a reboot on a server though (say Windows Update) you are out of luck.

`pm2-windows-service` did work for me, using `@innomizetech` fork, but I've had some issues, probably due to the user or its setup, or something else. Basically the service would start an old version of the saved process list, even though I tried `pm2 delete all`, `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`, `pm2 save`.

I resorted to a very simple home-made solution:

1. Create a file `pm2-resurrect.sh` in `C:\`, which contains the single line `pm2 resurrect`.
2. In Task Scheduler, add a new task that is run on boot, and select that it is run whether the user is logged in or not. You need to type the user password at this point which is saved for successive runs.
3. Set the task command to execute the file `C:\pm2-resurrect.sh`.

In my case I have Git for Windows which comes with bash, which opens the file and executes it. I didn't test it but I guess you could have a `.cmd` file with the same content.

Comment: You have to use: "pm2 -f save". Otherwise it will not clear the existing list (old list of apps). "pm2 save" is only useful as long as you update the actual list and it contains something. Point: Just always you "pm2 -f save" :)

Comment: This solution was the savior. It works like a charm. An additional tip is to set the environment variable `PM2_HOME` to `c:\users\<user>\.pm2` or something like that. This will help `PM2 resurrect` to pick up the dump file from this location. Also restart the machine for this scheme to work but if it is not possible to restart, run the created scheduled task manually.

Comment: I tried this solution, but Windows is not recognizing .sh files (??)

Comment: I have Git for Bash installed as I’ve said. You can also just use .cmd as a file extension, as written above

Answer (score 8):

easiest way & it works great hope it will help some

- I have created one  batch file *.bat in same folder
- `%windir%\system32\CMD.exe /k "start pm2 start myApp.js --name mySuperApp"`
- created windows "Task Scheduler" on startup works great...

Answer (score 1):

See [pm2-installer](https://github.com/jessety/pm2-installer#windows-install)

Readme is also make it clear how to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't access files from your app with that pm2 installation. You will be running your apps as a different user or something. For me it was useless

Comment: You can switch user to admin by creating folder inside root folder

Comment: @MarkCockram which method did work out for you?

Comment: I ended up doing something with the installation differently. I cant remember but the main takeaway is to use docker instead of pm2. There's my genuine advice.