# Hotw to open API controller with start up form app?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, api

I am currently in a situation where I need to call an API controller on the start-up of my PC. It can be with a win form application or something else. I want to make an API controller as a start-up because I will send MODBUS data to SQL with this API controller.
Is it possible?
(Normally I send MODBUS data to SQL with win form app but when I tried to connect MODBUS with API controller I could not get a connection because it is not possible to connect one device from different apps)

Comment: A few lines of PowreShell script and then schedule it to run in startup through Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your API controller with PM2 or Docker.

How to create a docker file: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

How to create pm2 a service for windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60477722/14890747