# PM2 couldn't start the app and the app ends up in "errored" status

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I am using Node/Express.js server on Windows Server 2012 R2 in the production and PM2.js to keep applications alive forever and to reload them without downtime. Since PM2 has limitations on Windows OS, I have chosen PM2-installer software to overcome them.

The server runs fine when I run with Node, so there is no issue with the server script.

```
node index.js
```

But, when I start the server with PM2, the server doesn't start and the status is "errored" (I had tried ecosystem file and cluster mode as well earlier with no luck).

```
pm2 start index.js
```

The logfile is empty, so there is no clue. Has anybody encountered this? Any solution?

**Update 1:**
I noticed the following error in service.log in C:\ProgramData\pm2\service

```
2021-03-23T23:13:56: PM2 log: App [server-plugin:0] starting in -fork mode-
2021-03-23T23:13:56: PM2 log: App [server-plugin:0] online
ERROR: 2021-03-23T23:13:56: PM2 error: Error: spawn node ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
3/23/2021, 11:13:56 PM: default/server-plugin@N/A - start - MANUAL
ERROR: 2021-03-23T23:13:56: PM2 error: Cancelling versioning data parsing
```

The error seems to indicate that it is not able to spawn node.js, but not sure why.

**Update 2:**
index.js is  small test App directly in root folder and contains just this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express'),
     https = require('https'),
     
const config = require('./config');

const hostname = config.hostname;
const port = config.port;

const app = express();

app.get("/*",(req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.headers);
  res.send(`<html><body><h1>Hello ${req.params[0] || 'World'} from ${port} port!</h1></body></html>`);

});

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app).listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at https://${hostname}:${port}`);
```

There is an accompanying config.js, the SSL files and node_modules sub-folder in the root folder. That's all.

Comment: does your express app has the "bin" directory? you could run it with pm2 start bin/www

Comment: locating index.js is not an issue as I have tried with relative or absolute path and I get the same error. I have also tried other express Apps too. This issue is consistent with all.

Comment: @Ravindra seems you don't understand it. Please show us the context of `index.js` file or check once again, does your project root diretory has `bin` folder, if it does, then start. `www` file, instead of `index.js`.

Comment: added information about the index.js in the description. I could reproduce the issue even with this small test app.

Comment: Have check recently by myself, via pm2. If the app launches directly via `node index.js` command, then try to launch it via `PM2` ecosystem file, or with `cluster` option, instead of `fork`.
Otherwise, the problem could be in `fs` module and pm2 access to it, since you are capable to access them when launching it directly, but pm2 as a service doesn't have enough permission for this directory. I have seen this before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66739573/how-to-allow-pm2-processes-access-to-filesystem#comment117978792_66739573

Comment: I got rid of fs module by switching to htttp instead of https and I still get the same error. I had tried cluster mode as well earlier with no luck

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to abandon `pm2-installer` and use a Task scheduler approach. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60929356/10402665) was the savior. It works like a charm. An additional tip is to set the environment variable `PM2_HOME` to `c:\users\<user>\.pm2` or something like that. This will help `PM2 resurrect` to pick up the dump file from this location. Also restart the machine for this scheme to work but if it is not possible to restart, run the created scheduled task manually.