# npm: pm2-windows-startup not working properly

Tags: node.js, windows, express, npm, pm2

I want my application to automatically restart on Windows reboot. I am using the `pm2-windows-startup` package provided by the **npm**. But, I am having an issue. When I restart the remote server and enter the `pm2 list` command in the **cmd**, it shows my application as `online`. However, when I hit the application's URL in my browser, I get a `This site can’t be reached` error.

I have followed the instructions provided by their official documentation.

[pm2-windows-startup](https://github.com/marklagendijk/node-pm2-windows-startup)

The only way my application runs after a restart is by using the below commands:

- `pm2 kill`
- `pm2 resurrect`

The server has Windows Server 2012 R2 operating system.

I don't know why is this happening despite following all the instructions provided by the repository. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this other package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-service

It install PM2 as a service where pm2-window-startup just wrote a startup string in registry.

If you want more informations, you have this post: [Windows: Auto start PM2 and node apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758985/windows-auto-start-pm2-and-node-apps)